# Which automation tool needs JavaScript or JQuery to be used more?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, test-automation-framework, javascript

I have started off my career in *manual* testing and an automation tool rarely. I would like to concentrate more on *automation* testing. I believe I have the object-oriented concepts in a good manner. I would like learn JavaScript and JQuery parallely, which can be used in automation scripting.

I would like to know which automation tool is more powerful in JavaScript and JQuery?

Also, I would like to know which tool is more in demand on market today?

Comment: Why did you pick out JavaScript and jquery?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In terms of UI automation, neither Javascript or jquery are used much at all.  I don't know of any tools that allow you to write UI automation in Javascript, although I bet if you looked you could find some.  Javascript and jquery are useful for unit testing or more advanced integration testing, but that doesn't sound like exactly what you were asking for.

Selenium 2.0 with Webdriver is a very popular open source UI automation framework that has multi-language support (.net languages such as C#, Java, Ruby, Python, etc).  Knowing Javascript can be useful when using Selenium since it does allow you to execute arbitrary Javascript as part of your tests, however it is usually a rare occurrence to work around a bug or do something more advanced.

Answer (score 5):

I recommend you try [TestCafe](http://testcafe.devexpress.com/).

It is a web testing framework, using which you can run tests on remote computers and mobile devices, in multiple browsers and on multiple machines simultaneously.

It also eliminates out of process browser plug-ins and provides wrapper-free access to DOM via jQuery or a browser's API. The built-in traffic analysis tool notifies you about missing resources, response codes and JavaScript errors, and checks page elements’ visibility.

TestCafe is free for non-commercial use. It is only chargeable if a product, application or website you plan to test with TestCafe brings in an income.

Disclaimer: I work on the TestCafe team. I'd love to help you learn more about it and to hear any feedback.

Answer (score 4):

I use PhantomJS to regression test the look and layout of Web Pages, it is written in Javascript.  You might also want to look into CasperJS, PhantomCSS and dpxdt (developed by some testers at Google) which are all related.

TestComplete generates code in JScript (equivalent to JavaScript), which is a pretty powerful functional testing tool.  As mentioned above, TestCafe is also JavaScript based and is pretty neat in my opinion.

Personally I would not think much about the specific language used by an automaton.  It is definitely a plus if the language used to automate tests is the same as the language used by the Software Under Test, one reason being you can get expert help from the Software Developers if you are not one yourself.  But the thing is, when you have mastered one programming language A the benefits of using a ready made automaton scriptable in another language B usually outweigh the cost of getting used to that language B.

Answer (score 3):

Jasmine is a behavior-driven development framework for testing JavaScript code.

http://pivotal.github.io/jasmine/

Comment: Can i use Jasmine if i have custom coded game with Javascript, jquery, html5 for running automated tests @Francis? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look on Karma which is based on NodeJs and specifically designed for AngularJs.

http://karma-runner.github.io/

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you go for Protractor which is a native automation tool for AngularJS, which works purely on JavaScript.

Protractor is currently in huge demand as AngularJS & angular is being used in many applications.
Also for using Selectors it uses CSS , for which it uses Jquery like syntax.

Protractor uses Jasmine by default as its native unit testing framework.

I think **Protractor**, is the right tool for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

[Sahi Web Test Automation Tool](http://sahi.co.in/) is a very good automation tool. It is based on javascript language, you can learn to use it quite easily and it can manage even more complex web application.
I use the open-source edition and I can recommend it, especialy if you feel comfortable with javascript.